# Cannot edit state in Pinia store using action

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, pinia

I have an error whenever I try to edit the state using an action in the Pinia store in my Quasar project.

Here is the store-file:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


export const useSchemaStore = defineStore('schema', {
    state: () => ({
        schemas: [],
    }),
    getters: {
        getSchemas( state ) {
            return state.schemas;
        },
        getActiveSchemaById: (state) => (id) => {
            return state.schemas.find((schema) => schema.data[0].id === id);
        }
    },
    actions: {
        addSchemas(schemas) {
            this.schemas = schemas;
        },
        createNewSchema(schemaName: string, ) {
            const newSchema = {
                data: [
                    {
                        id: uuidv4(),
                        label: schemaName,
                    }
                ],
            };
            console.log(newSchema)
            this.schemas = [...this.schemas, newSchema];
        },
        updateSchema(schemaId: string, data: object) {
            const schema = this.schemas.find((schema) => schema.data[0].id === schemaId);
            if (!schema) return console.log('schema not found'); // Schema not found

            console.log(schema)

            // Update the cloned schema
            for (const key in data) {
                console.log(key)
                const elementIndex = schema.data[1].data.findIndex(element => element.elementId === data.elementId.value);
                if (elementIndex !== -1) {
                    // Update the property in a reactive way
                    schema.data[1].data[elementIndex][key] = data[key].value;
                }
            }
        }

    },
});
```

And here is the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'componentId' of object '#<Object>'
    at Proxy.updateSchema (schema-store.ts:45:55)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (pinia.js?v=fd005944:1049:22)
    at store.<computed> (pinia.js?v=fd005944:750:44)
    at updateSchema (SchemaCard.vue:82:17)
    at callWithErrorHandling (chunk-USCHSUQN.js?v=fd005944:1824:18)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (chunk-USCHSUQN.js?v=fd005944:1832:17)
    at emit (chunk-USCHSUQN.js?v=fd005944:2280:5)
    at navigateOnClick (quasar_dist_quasar_esm_js.js?v=fd005944:2108:7)
    at onClick (quasar_dist_quasar_esm_js.js?v=fd005944:2649:7)
    at callWithErrorHandling (chunk-USCHSUQN.js?v=fd005944:1824:18)
```

The error in question happens whenever I try to alter the state using the `updateSchema` action.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We'd need to know the values of your state and different variables.  What is the current state before calling the action, and what are the input values used with the action (`schemaId`, `data`)?